# To prove or disprove set equality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove this:

$$(A \setminus B)\times(C \setminus D)=(A \times C)\setminus(B \times D)$$

I don't understand how to do it, how do I get Cartesian product without the contents of the set? I tried simplifying it and got:

$$(A\cap\overline{B})(C\cap\overline{D})=(A \times C)\cap\overline{(B \times D)}$$
Cannot proceed further.

Comment: Should be $C\setminus D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not true. Let $A=C=\{1,2\}$ and $B=D=\{1\}$. Then, $(A\setminus B)\times (C\setminus D)=\{(2,2)\}$, but $(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)=\{(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$.

What *is* true is that $(A\setminus B)\times (C\setminus D)\subseteq (A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$.

Comment: So it can be disproved, right?

Comment: The example itself disproves the statement.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, by substitution(like in your example) I can prove that the equality is not true?

Comment: Yes, because an equation must always be true.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by ‘element-chasing’. To show that

$$(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)\subseteq(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)\,,\tag{1}$$

let $\langle x,y\rangle\in(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)$. Then $x\in A\setminus B$, and $y\in C\setminus D$. This implies that $x\in A$, $x\notin B$, $y\in C$, and $y\notin D$. Thus, $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times C$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\notin B\times D$, and therefore $\langle x,y\rangle\in(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$; this establishes $(1)$.

However, if you use the same approach to try to show that

$$(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)\subseteq(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)\,,\tag{2}$$

you’ll find that you run into trouble. Suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle\in(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$; then $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times C$, so $x\in A$ and $y\in C$, which is what we want. This also ensures that $\langle x,y\rangle\notin B\times D$, but unfortunately that does **not** ensure that $x\notin B$ **and** $y\notin D$: it only guarantees that $x\notin B$ **or** $y\notin D$ (or possibly both). And that tells you that you should spend some time trying to construct a counterexample to $(2)$.

For instance, what if $C=D$? Then the righthand side of $(2)$ is empty, so if we can choose $A,B,C$, and $D$ in such a way that the lefthand side is **not** empty, we’ll have our counterexample. Remember, we’re going to take $C=D$, so we want $(A\times C)\setminus(B\times C)$ to be non-empty. That’s easy: just make sure that $A\setminus C\ne\varnothing$. Let’s take $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=C=D=\{0\}$: then

$$(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)=\{\langle 1,0\rangle\}\,,$$

but

$$(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)=\varnothing\,.$$